# dynamics ax ssrs deploy error

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, dynamics-ax-2012

I've got this error when I tried to deploy SSRS report in Visual Studio.
(DAX 2012 kernel 6.0.1108.6510 app 6.0.1108.670 solution 6.1.1108.670)

Error 1 A call to the Microsoft Dynamics AX SRSFrameworkService service failed. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.43.6.57:8201. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\DynamicsTools\Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Design.Reporting.Modeling.targets 466

10.43.6.57:8201 is old address new should be 10.43.6.91:8201

Where I can change it?

In AX form SSRSServerFarm address is new:(NLDDAXDBS02TR, http://NLDDAXDBS02TR/Reports, 01@NLDDAXDBS02TR)
I run Visual Studio like this "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /AxConfig "c:\Users\Username\Desktop\DEV.axc" with correct config file

in axc file I don't have 10.43.6.57 or old dns NLDDAXDBS01T
I scanned and replaced values in registry on client and server machine, checked all files on client and server machine, checked all values in database.
Also restarted AOSes, SSRS service, and client RDP session.

Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Configuration and perform a Refresh Configuration didn't help

Full CIL Compilation, Deactivate BIServices, Activate BIServices also didn't help

Running Visual Studio as Admin - same result

nslookup says: NLDDAXDBS01T - 10.43.6.57 NLDDAXDBS02TR - 10.43.6.91

System Administration > Setup > Business intelligence > Report Servers is correct because i tried to deploy from another rdp server and it works fine

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Configuration and perform a Refresh Configuration didn't help

Comment: ... Full CIL Compilation, Deactivate BIServices, Activate BIServices also didn't help

Comment: You write "10.43.6.57:8201 is old address new should be 10.43.6.57:8201". These two IP addresses and port numbers are identical, is that a typo? Can you access the report server with its URL in an internet browser?

Comment: sorry new should be 10.43.6.91 it works fine 10.43.6.57 doesn't

Comment: Also do you run Visual Studio as Administrator? And does deploying the report from the AOT work?

Comment: I tried to run Visual Studio also as Admin - doesn't work. Deploying from AOT works fine.

Comment: Did you try to access the report server with its URL from an Internet browser? What does [nslookup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490721.aspx) tell you as IP address for the report server?

Comment: Also take a look at [AX 2012 R2: Not able to deploy ssrs report](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/127752)

Comment: report server works fine with all reports, i just can't deploy new one. they also work in browser. nslookup 
NLDDAXDBS01T - 10.43.6.57
NLDDAXDBS02TR - 10.43.6.91 
Already tried all from that link

Comment: Ok, I'm out of ideas for now. You may want to edit the Information you gave in the comments into your question so others don't need to read through all the comments.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: [Same question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/189623) in AX community. The last suggestion by Iulian Cordobin (reinstall Visual Studio Tools for AX) sounds reasonable, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. I know. It is my question in AX community. This suggestion I left for last. I'm able to do my work from another rdp server, so it is not urgent and I can play with this error little more. I want to find the root of evil :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain the default report server is setup correctly in Ax?

Found under:

> System Administration > Setup > Business intelligence > Report
>   Servers

Comment: Wouldn't that also cause problems when deploying from AOT? OP says in the comments this works.

Comment: System Administration > Setup > Business intelligence > Report Servers
is correct because i tried to deploy from another rdp server and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Check your business connector configuration to make sure it's connecting to the right environment, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569654.aspx

I think Visual Studio deploys to AX based on that business connector AXC, so if that's pointed to an incorrect environment that has the "old" SSRS setup, it would explain your issue.

Comment: As I said before I checked and replaces all registry values with old address. And I also checked BC config. Looks correct.

Comment: You shouldn't really need to make changes in the registry. If you have an AXC filepath listed in the registry, that usually takes priority over all changes listed. Try using Visual Studio on a different machine. Are you using VS locally, on the AOS, or on the SRS server? Check the BC connection settings in the control panel from them all.

Comment: I made changes to be sure. As i said in question: I tried to deploy from another rdp server and it works fine. So i think it is not about something inside ax or ssrs server or database, because it works from another rdp server.

Comment: You keep saying as you said before, but I don't see in the question where you clearly state you are deploying from an RDP machine, nor is your question very clear. Try running VS on the RDP machine without using the *.axc to launch it. Start eliminating variables. Check on SSRS to see if it's using an AXC file https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh389774.aspx

Comment: May be not very clear but in question: System Administration > Setup > Business intelligence > Report Servers is correct because i tried to deploy from another rdp server and it works fine.

Comment: If i try without axc then i get Disconnected from the aos in application explorer. What do you mean eliminate variables? Which variables?

Comment: So if the AOT doesn't connect after launching VS without AXC, but it did before, then the AXC is functioning but may be incorrect somehow. From the RDP machine that works correctly, are you using `/AxConfig` there too? If yes, copy that `*.AXC` file from that RDP and replace the other one on the failing RDP. That should solve it. If it doesn't solve it, it would point me to think you need to uninstall/reinstall some things.

Comment: about "Check on SSRS to see if it's using an AXC file technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh389774.aspx" - I tried but it didn't help.

"from that RDP and replace the other one on the failing RDP" - I use same axc file

As I said to FH-Inway in comments reinstalling vs ax addin is my last step. But now I'm trying to find why it is so.

Comment: So is it working? It sounds like you're saying "I've already tried that" to most of our suggestions, and not re-checking them in detail, and possibly missing something obvious. Keep in mind, Most people aren't reading every comment you have between everyone else. Maybe you've messed something up in the registry. Look here for registry notes http://www.alexondax.com/2015/12/some-notes-on-dynamics-ax-2012-and.html

Comment: No. It isn't. I'm checking the registry every time when i try new suggestion. I didn't try all combinations of suggestions so I don't give up. Most useful things i'm adding to the end of question.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem one time due to multiple AOS and SSRS instance, or you might stop AOS service while user still using.
First, you need to make sure Report servers configuration point correctly to SSRS instance.
Then, stop all AOS service, go to reporting service login with correct instance and check everything again.
Then, perform full compilation using [AXbuild.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528954.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) , Full CIL.
Start AOS service and check.
Let us know result.

Comment: I have only one SSRS and one AOS for this application. I tried everything which I wrote but with no success. After that I reinstalled VS and VS Tools for AX. So I can't test it now. Sorry.